# Как в TypeScript валедировать json с помощью interface?

Tags: json, typescript, валидация, сериализация, десериализация

Как можно проверить JSON сериализованную строку, на соответствие интерфейсу ?

В Python есть https://docs.pydantic.dev/ которая делает то что мне нужно, но вот в TypeScript не нахожу достойные варианты.

Например, я хочу чтобы это работало так:

```
// Объявляю интерфейс
interface TClient {
    name: string;
    id: number;
}
// Я получаю откуда-то JSON строку
in_data = '{ name: "stackoverflow", id: 1 }';
// Я выполняю валидацию строки. Если ошибка то будет undefined
ВалидныйJSON = МагическаяФункцияДляВалидации(in_data, TClient);
if (ВалидныйJSON !== undefined) {
    // Я использую валидный JSON
    console.log(ВалидныйJSON.name);
} else {
    console.error("Ошибка валидации");
}
```

Я знаю, interface после компиляции не существует в .js файле. Но если бы я создавал такую библиотеку, то я бы нашел способ хранить interface(или его аналогичную копию), чтобы производить по нему валидацию.

Comment: Погуглить ts runtime interface validator. Например https://github.com/gristlabs/ts-interface-checker

Comment: На первый взгляд годно, но 300 звезд это маловато. Не ужели у самого популярного ЯП в мире, и у самого единственного ЯП для браузеров, нет чего по популярнее ?

Comment: Ну я встречал ещё несколько которые генерят из типов JSON Schema и дальше валидирую по ней. Но в общем случае в задаче очень много крайних случаев, и универсального решения нет.

Comment: Я бы поверил в это, если бы не было https://docs.pydantic.dev/ который везде используют в Python, как универсальный инструмент для валидации JSON. Поэтому в Ts должен быть такой аналог !

Comment: Тут проблема не в JSON, а в TS. Можно накрутить такой сложный интерфейс, что проверка фактически сведётся к запуску компилятора TS в рантайме. Простые интерфейсы неплохо ложатся на JSON Schema. Например ts-json-schema-generator

Comment: Ошибка в райнтайме из за невалидного JSON гораздо хуже, чем пару миллисекунд на валидацию.

Comment: Пришел невалидный JSON, ну отдали мы его парсеру, он нам скажет - плохо... и что далее? В чем отличие от ошибки во время выполнения? Если ожидаешь возможность кривых данных, всегда можно проверить наличие нужных тегов и обернуть все в try catch. Что то, что то приведет к невыполнению нужного куска кода и пойдет по "запасному"(catch) пути

Comment: Товарищи, не будь всем известно https://docs.pydantic.dev/ с 12к звезд на гитхабе, вы бы могли придумать разные причины, почему можно не делать валидацию так как в ней, но это уже стандарт, и крупный бизнес использует его. Поэтому, 12к звезд на гитхабе дает ответ, почему такой вариант востребован, и нужен аналог для TS.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript не предоставляет функционала для проверки на соответствие интерфейсу в рантайме, так как обычно TS-код собирается в Javascript, где интерфейсы пропадают, так как не являются частью языка.

На данный момент есть несколько библиотек для проверки на соответствие схеме. От себя могу порекомендовать [zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod)

В вашем случае код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
import { z } from "zod";

const TClientSchema = zod.object({
  name: zod.string(),
  id: zod.string(),
});

// extract the inferred type
type TClient = zod.infer<typeof TClientSchema>;

const inData = {name:"stackoverflow", id:1};

try {
  TClientSchema.parse(inData, {});

  // do something
} catch (error) {
  // error
}
```

Удачи!

Comment: Это пока лучший вариант которы я видел.